# Data and File not getting stored in DB and Directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know where I'm going wrong. I know I am an amatuer and my code is not great. Here my JQuery is sending the data but I cannot seem to get the data and files stored. I used FormData() in JQuery. Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['audio_lesson'])) {
      $title = preg_replace("#[<>]#i", "", $_POST['title']);
      $description = preg_replace("#[<>]#i", "", $_POST['description']);
      $category = preg_replace("#[<>]#i", "", $_POST['category']);
      $tags = $_POST['tags'];
      //$font = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#i", "", $_POST['font']);
      echo $post->Post($_FILES["post_files"], $title, $description, $category, $tags);
    }
```

And:

```
public function Post($post_files, $title, $description, $category, $tags){
     $session = $_SESSION['id'];
     $universal = new universal();
     $name = preg_replace("#[\'\"]#i", "", $post_files['name']);
     $size = $post_files['size'];
     $tmp_name = $post_files['tmp_name'];
     $error = $post_files['error'];
     $ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $name)));
     $allowed = array("mp3");

     if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
       if ($error == 0) {
         $new_name = time().".".$ext;
         if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "../../folder/".$session."/audio/"."rand_".$name)) {

           $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO post (user_id, type, time, about, description, category, tags) VALUES (:user, :type, now(), :about, :description, :category, :tags)");

           $query->execute(array(":user" => $session, ":type" => "audio", ":about" => $title,":description" => $description, ":category" => $category, ":tags" => $tags));

         }
       } else {
         return "Error!!";
       }
     }
   }
```

I have added my HTML form and the JQuery/AJAX code in a codepen, to avoid breaching stacked's publishing policy and limitations.

Please find the HTML form and AJAX in this codepen here: https://codepen.io/masoodbawa/pen/VwZBvWB

I need the form data to submit and store in the DB as well as the file to uploaded to the directory.

Any ideas please? TIA

Comment: Does your code report any errors?

Comment: It's not reporting any errors. The Jquery and AJAX identifies the file object as [File Object] and the data as strings. I do not know how to test the above PHP code if they are in all seperate files.